# Preserve RightNow chat on page refresh

Tags: web, chat, rightnow-crm

I have a question I'm sure some of you have stumbled on to. We are using the RightNow 14-1-0-1 SP3, mainly for the chat. On one of our products the chat is web based, we just take the chat_landing page from the *interface*.custhelp.com put it into a div with an iframe containing it and use it to communicate with our clients. There is something from RN's side that prevents us from keeping the chat when the user visits another page or refreshes. On the RN side of things the popup with terminate/wrap up comes up, and we are unable to continue the session. Anyone knows a solution for this one? Maybe it's a widget somewhere or a setting?

Comment: As far as I know, this would be very difficult to achieve

Answer (score 0):

If the page refreshes or navigates to another page, the connection between the browser and the chat session is terminated, per the behavior that you mention.  If you want to implement some sort of navigation while chat takes place, you could implement a mechanism that fetches that new page content through ajax and load it dynamically into the DOM instead of through browser navigation.  That will only work for links that you display on your site and the issue would still happen when you use your browser's navigation, but the primary use case for the implementation that you mention is to allow a user to navigate on your site or knowledge base, not the full internet, so that might be an acceptable solution for you.